# Running pdflatex from a python script (3.5.2)

Tags: python, subprocess, pdflatex

I am trying to run pdflatex from a python script using the subprocess module but for some reason python cannot find the pdflatex module. I can call pdflatex from a command prompt and it works without any issues. I have verified that the path to pdflatex exists under environment variables. I have a MikTex 2.9 installation which works from TexWorks as well as Texstudio.

I have installed the latex package for python (which also uses the subprocess module) but that too cannot find pdflatex.

I am running Win 10 but I can reproduce the problem on Win 7 and Win 8. I had found a solution for Win 7 based on the env parameter but cannot find it now for some reason.

Does anyone have any idea for how to get pdflatex to work properly with Python?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should try [latexrun](https://github.com/aclements/latexrun). This takes care of running all latex related commands.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same thing a while ago and came up with a series of solutions to achieve this, I created a [repo for the project](https://github.com/rishi23root/resume-curator) it will be hard to explain each step you can take this as a reference to start the solve, and communicate in the repo for any queries.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35081071)